# UICollectionView: Waterfall layout with Drag & Drop

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I am using CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout as the layout for my collectionView, since my cells do all have different sizes. But I would also like to implement drag & drop in my collectionView. The libraries I have found would not allow me to implement both at the same time. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it, I used one of the existing Drag 'n Drop libraries and made sure it inherited from the CHTCollectionView instead of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout, this worked pretty good! Still some errors to work out, but the beginning is there

Comment: Sorry to dig up an old message, but any chance your able to share your code, or offer any other guidance?  I've been playing with this idea for the morning, and its proving to be more time consuming than I thought!

Comment: Well all I did was change the line that usually inherits UICollectionViewFlowLayout and change it to inherit CHTCollectionView.